# android:alwaysRetainTaskState doesn't work properly

Tags: android

I have a problem. After searching how can I retain the changes made in an activity,I've added `android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"` and `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`to my main activity. The problem is: I open the Settings from the action bar, go to General, then click back button in the action bar and it takes me to Settings and then if I click back it takes me back to General.

Another problem is: I open the 3rd activity and go to settings, then press back and go to the 3rd activity and then if I press back it takes me back to settings.

Both SettingsActivity and the 3rd one are have MainActivity as parrent.